# How to use a raw string for latex with a string variable?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I was trying to use latex in one of my labels for a matplotlib plot. As shown on matplotlib website, using an **r** in the beginning of the string helps me do that. as shown below:

> plt.title(r'$\alpha > \beta$')

But now, I want to replace the inside of the string (**'$\alpha > \beta$'**) with a variable. I tried some combinations but it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Python 3.6+, you can use an `f`-string, which also works with a raw string:

```
u = 5
plt.title(rf'$\alpha > {u}$')
```

Otherwise, the `str.format` function would also work:

```
plt.title(r'$\alpha > {}$'.format(u))
```

Output:

[image]