# Append string variable to LaTeX based raw string

Tags: python, latex

Trying to append an integer as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66130781/1176573) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55514931/1176573).

Requirement:

```py
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
N = 128
text = r'$QFT=\frac{1}{\sqrt{'+str(N)+'}} \begin{bmatrix}'

text = text + r'1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\'
text = text + r' \end{bmatrix}$'
display(Markdown(text))
```

Tried: `IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple`

```py
N = str(128)
text = r'$QFT=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \begin{bmatrix}'.format(N)
```

But either of these don't work. Note, here `text` is LaTeX based string.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-do-i-print-curly-brace-characters-in-a-string-while-using-format, in your case that probably should look something like ` r'$QFT=\frac{{1}}{{\sqrt{{{N}}}}} \begin{{bmatrix}}'.format(N=N)`

Comment: `text = r'$QFT=\frac{{1}}{{\sqrt{{N}}}}\begin{{bmatrix}}'.format(N)` This renders the LaTeX well but its not replacing the `N` by value `128`.

Comment: in your statement you posted in the comment above you're missing extra `{}` around `N` and you need to specify `.format(N=N)` because the formatting function doesn't know which placeholder it should fill in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double each curly bracket if it's a part of the string:

```
> N = 128
> text = r"$QFT = \frac{{1}}{{\sqrt{{{0}}}}} \begin{{bmatrix}}".format(N)
> print(text)
$SQFT = \frac{1}{\sqrt{128} \begin{bmatrix}
```

In case you want to use a parameter `N` in the string, then use the explicit parameter `format(N=N)` to get the same effect:

```
> text = r"$QFT = \frac{{1}}{{\sqrt{{{N}}}}} \begin{{bmatrix}}".format(N=N)
> print(text)
$SQFT = \frac{1}{\sqrt{128} \begin{bmatrix}
```

Comment: May I know why you have appended an extra `S` before `QFT`?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo